# Restore button for iOS non-consumable in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Apple have unfortunately rejected my app for not having a restore button. I wanted to have a seamless experience for the user but there are some problems.

```
- (void)purchaseProUpgrade
{ 
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

   // User is prompted for iTunes username and password here (1)
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

// Then this delegate Function Will be fired
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    if( queue.transactions.count == 0 ) {

        [self setUpgradeProductId];

       // User is prompted for iTunes username and password here (2)
        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId];
       [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];                                                                 

    }else {

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:NULL];
    }
  }
```

Is the above a good solution? The logic would be:

1. User presses button to remove in-app purchase.
2. Check if the user has already made a purchase (user has to enter username and password)
3. If user has already made a purchase, restore
4. If user has not already made a purchase,prompt for payment (user has to enter password again).

The problems with this approach are:
1. An additional server call
2. User has to enter details twice.

Has anyone actually implemented a Restore button that they can demonstrate?

Comment: Why would you have a button for the user to remove an in-app purchase?  An app uninstall will do that.  How would you do your step #2 with out forcing a username and password?

Comment: How do I know whether or not to display the restore button?  That is, my code doesn't know whether or not they have already made a purchase.  Or does it?

Answer (score 11):

No need of implementing your own logic
Just implement this

```
- (IBAction)restorePreviousTransaction:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

This will call this method

```
 - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
   case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(restoreTransaction:)]) {
                    [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                    return;                
}
```

This will call these delegate methods for transaction success or failure

```
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

Comment: i encountered with an issue . when i press restore button and use appstore ID by which no in-app purchase is done then in this case -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error is not called . is it normal or something is wrong ?

Comment: Yes its normal. Instead it will call **-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue** with 0 in `SKPaymentQueue` ie queue.

Comment: You need to check queue value is 0 or not

Comment: which property to check in SKPaymentQueue for 0 ? please provide the code if u can i didnt understand that exactly ?

Comment: I am implementing non-consumable and `restorePreviousTransaction` never fires `updatedTransactions` method. Same code perfectly works for `auto-renewable subscriptions` 

Comment: Don't relay on paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished, if during the restore process, device loses connection or app crashes or iOS takes user to app store for cvv code verification, on running the app again, StoreKit will call the paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions, but not the final paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished!

Comment: how to get last transaction detail or restore last complete transaction? This above method gives me lots of id and not given last purchase id

Answer (score 7):

Add this code to the page where you had added the restore button:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {  
     NSLog(@"%@",error);
}

// Call This Function
- (void) checkPurchasedItems
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

//Then this delegate Function Will be fired
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];

        NSLog(@"%@",purchasedItemIDs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple rejects application with In App Purchase, that does not have a restore purchase button. In the app view, add a restore button.
Then in the In App Purchase helper class, add the following method:

```
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]; 
}
```

Now call this method from the button click action and it will restore the previous purchase.

Answer (score 0):

```
*- (IBAction)restorePreviousTransaction:(id)sender {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
delegate method call:
 - (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
   case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(restoreTransaction:)]) {
                    [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                    return;                
}
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions)
    {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
        NSLog(@"%@",purchasedItemIDs);
    }
}*
```