# Apple reject because of In app purchase not implement restore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, restore

I got rejected by Apple with a message saying:

> ... Additionally, we found that while your app offers In-App Purchase(s)
>   that can be restored, it does not include the required "Restore"
>   feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased In-App
>   Purchase(s), as specified in Restoring Transactions section of the
>   In-App Purchase Programming Guide:
>
> "...if your application supports product types that must be
>   restorable, you must include an interface that allows users to restore
>   these purchases. This interface allows a user to add the product to
>   other devices or, if the original device was wiped, to restore the
>   transaction on the original device."
>
> To restore previously purchased In-App Purchase products, it would be
>   appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore
>   process when the "Restore" button is tapped by the user.
>
> For more information about restoring transactions and verifying store
>   receipt, please refer to the In-App Purchase Programming Guide.
>   ...

And I found this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975312/no-restore-button-for-in-app-purchase-causes-rejection), and I followed the sample code , but after I called

```
- (void) checkPurchasedItems{
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

another delegate was not fired!

```
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

It only popups an alert view, to let you enter your Apple ID ... and nothing happened?

I set a break point, but it wouldn't stop as the example said.

Any ideas on what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not post all of it ... I think that' fine ? Or should I delete it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restore button for ios non consumable in app purchase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113047/restore-button-for-ios-non-consumable-in-app-purchase)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In addition to adding `restoreCompletedTransactions`, you need to handle how your iaps are actually restored to the user and how the content is provided to the user.

Basically, you need to recall the way you provide the item to your user when they originally purchased it.

### [**Here is a good tutorial.**](http://nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/)

For **example**, this is how I restore products in one of my apps.

### Restore Transaction

```
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    isRestoring = YES;

    [self recordTransaction: transaction];

    /* This is where I provide the content to the user: */
    [self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

### Transaction Completed

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

### Payment Queue

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    /// user has cancelled
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hideRestoring" object:nil];
                }
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

### Provide the Content

```
- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    int index;

    NSMutableDictionary * purchased = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:EXTRAS_PATH];

    NSArray * availableProducts = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SCANNER_IN_APP_PURCHASES]];

    if ( isRestoring )
    {
        for ( index = 0; index < [availableProducts count]; index++ )
        {
            //NSLog(@"productIdentifier: %@",productIdentifier);
            //NSLog(@"Product: %@",[availableProducts objectAtIndex:index]);

            if ( [productIdentifier isEqualToString:[[availableProducts objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"BundleID"]] )
            {
                [purchased setObject:[availableProducts objectAtIndex:index] forKey:productIdentifier];

                [purchased writeToFile:EXTRAS_PATH atomically:YES];

                [_purchasedProducts addObject:productIdentifier];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        index = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kTempProductPurchasingIndex"] intValue];

        if ( [productIdentifier isEqualToString:[[availableProducts objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"BundleID"]] )
        {
            [purchased setObject:[availableProducts objectAtIndex:index] forKey:productIdentifier];

            [purchased writeToFile:EXTRAS_PATH atomically:YES];

            [_purchasedProducts addObject:productIdentifier];
        }
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: thank you sir ,I will try your sample code now .

Comment: Well, my code isn't actually going to help your situation. My advice should though, just recall the method you use when you provide the purchase originally.

Comment: I know , just need to edit some place .also in my code

Comment: @WrightsCS, I have uploaded an app which has 1 inapp purchase that was accepted. And uploaded an app which has 23 inapp purchases that was rejected. Is there any rules for how many inapp purchase we should add "restore" button?

Answer (score 10):

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

Add The previous line as well. Your `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` function should get called.

Comment: Your answer is right , but the more detail solution is answer by @WrightsCS .So I vote your answer up ,sorry about that.