# Restoring In App purchase without 'buy' prompt? Is it possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit

I currently have my in-app purchase 'restore' button,

It *does* work, but essentially it asks the user mid way through the process to 'buy' the upgrade (just like it would have on a normal in-app) I am worried this will

a) be rejected by apple
b) scare the user into thinking they are paying again

Is there any way I can change it so it has perhaps a different message?

```
-(IBAction)restore:(id)sender
{=
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
     addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
     restoreCompletedTransactions];

    UIAlertView *alert;

    alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Restoring Your Purchases, Please Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    // Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
    indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [alert addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator release];

    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature];=
}

-(void)productPurchased
{
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if (view.tag==2000)
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    } 

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Thank you" message:@"Your restore was successful." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

// error restore
- (void)failed
{
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if (view.tag==2000)
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your restore has failed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely it's possible, in fact it is necessary. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11200519/171206) to a somewhat similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11200460/171206).

Essentially when you press the restore button, the user should be asked to verify their account; this is handled by `StoreKit`. If IA purchases are found for the account, then the process should begin restoring the purchases in the same manner as if they were buying the item for the first time, only without the prompt to actually purchase.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I must admit I am struggling to code it at the moment, its frustrating for such a small function to add!

So would you suggest replacing my code above with your code instead? Or can you help modify my code above?
Kind regards
Agnelli

Comment: Unfortunately, you will have to figure this one out with the help given here. How else do you expect to learn the SDK and how to properly put things together and make them work? If you **just can't** seem to figure it out, see my profile for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using MKStoreKit. Just enable iCloud in your app and MKStoreKit takes care of the rest. the other devices will "see" the purchase as "bought" without even opening the store page.

PS: I wrote MKStoreKit