# in-app purchase restore button -- provide it even though one doesn't know whether or not the user has purchased the content?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I have had an app update rejected because I don't have a restore button for my in-app purchase.  What I don't understand is -- when I first show the iAP to the user, I don't know if they have already made the purchase or not.  Am I still supposed to show them the restore button?

For a question on how to implement the restore button, see [Apple reject because of In app purchase not implement restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200460/apple-reject-because-of-in-app-purchase-not-implement-restore).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this: The user has your app and buys the IAP. They then get a new device and install your app. The first thing they want to do on the new device is tap on your "Restore Purchases" button so they get back their paid for content.

This assumes of course you are talking about non-consumables or perhaps subscription type purchases.

Basically, any app that sells non-consumables must have a "Restore Purchases" button. You should always show the button. Of course the user may tap the button and there may be nothing to restore. This is fine. Simply display a message telling the user that there was nothing to restore.