# Confusion over in app purchase rejected for not including "restore" button

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Recently I submitted an app with an in app purchase and it got rejected because of the following:

> We found that while your app offers In-App Purchase(s) that can be
>   restored, it does not include the required "Restore" feature to allow
>   users to restore the previously purchased In-App Purchase(s)

I have followed the instructions exactly and have implemented as following:

```
- (void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction:transaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction: transaction];
    [self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Obviously, I don't have a button that triggers restoreTransaction just yet, but what I'm confused about is does Apple simply require this as a formality to the user to reduce confusion? Because both of the above methods do the exact same thing, and I notice when I try to buy the in-app purchase after having already doing so prior, it will say something like "upgrading for free since you already have purchased it".

So my first question is, is the purpose of having a restore button simply to prevent the user from freaking out cause they'll probably be scared to push "purchase" again? i.e. I don't need to keep track of my customer purchase history in a database or something?

Second question is, what if a user who hasn't previously purchased the app pushes "restore" out of curiosity, will it go ahead and purchase the in app purchase for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple likes you to have a `Restore All Purchases`-Button
What should happen is fetching the list of purchases from Apple.
A user should not have to click on purchase when he wants to restore something (Confusion about buying or not, like in the early times of the AppStore)

When you trigger a restore it won't purchase anything. It is just a restore what I purchased and if not it just fails but doesn't purchase anything.

If you're not sure about your In-App Purchase Code you could read [Introduction to In-App Purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) from Raywenderlich.com. The article also features a super reusable in-app purchase helper code.
The method to call when the user clicks `Restore All Purchases` in their In-App Purchase helper would be `- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions;`

Answer (score 1):

The first question is a bit subjective, which is generally not well received on SO, but I will try to answer it regardless.

A lot of the Apple Human Interface Guidelines focus on making an application's "feel" match the device, as explained [in the guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).  While a lot of this is focused on the size of elements working well on a device screen, including a restore button is part of the feel as well.  Apple, somewhat arbitrarily, decided that apps need a restore button if they offer in-app purchases to fit the feel of their system.

The second question actually seems a bit like a previous question that was confusingly marked as off-topic.  The question dealt more with how to set up the restore, but I think it may benefit you and prevent the duplicate code you have above.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200460/apple-reject-because-of-in-app-purchase-not-implement-restore) is the link.  Specifically, the accepted answer by Wrights looks like a good template to follow to make sure you don't actually purchase things for the user with the restore function.

In the event that the question is ever deleted, [here](http://www.nixsolutions.com/blog/development/iphone/in-app-purchase-tutorial/) is a tutorial that answer suggests.

Hope that provides some help.