# consumable in-app-purchase in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins

I have implemented consumable in-app purchase in my iPhone application.When user install and then uninstall the application, his purchases are maintained by my server.

So my question is that if I have to put restore purchases button in my application??? Or it will ok that in-app purchases are handled by my server.

My application is based on 1 year subscription plan. After expiring the time period, it will again prompt buy add-on message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)No need to put restore purchases in your application.
It ll only use in non consumable in-app.

And as you said subscription, than you have to use subscription in - app. And in it you have to use it.
Below links will help you to restore in-app
1) [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)
2) [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761556/restore-already-bought-in-app-purchases-on-iphone)
3) [stackOverflow -2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113047/restore-button-for-ios-non-consumable-in-app-purchase)

Comment: But apple has rejected my application and suggested me to implement my in-app purchase using non-renewing in-app purchase model. But my application is work perfectly in the case of reinstallation.My server is handling all this issues.

Comment: See my updated answer... And yes, i think u have used wrong in-app.

Comment: ok.... But how can I implement restore in-app purchases.Can u please give me some idea regarding this???

Comment: But I have to implement restore in-app purchase using phonegap.